# With ApolloClient, Having trouble adding basic credential to header

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I've got working code that creates an ApolloClient that is based on code at the URL:  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/client/#create-an-apollo-client .  It is:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: graphqlBase,
    credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
    fetch
});

return new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState)
});
```

When I add what I think should be valid middleware and replace the code `link: httpLink` with: `middlewareLink.concat(httpLink)` and `middlewarelink` defined as follows:

```
const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    operation.setContext({
        headers: {
            authorization: 'xxx' || null
        }
    });
    return forward(operation);
});
```

My working query now errors with this error

```
"GraphQL.ExecutionError: A query is required. ---> GraphQL.ExecutionError: A query is required.\r\n   at GraphQL.DocumentExecuter.ValidateOptions
```

I'm querying with

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

<ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <PageComponent {...pageProps} />
</ApolloProvider>
```

It seems my query itself is getting removed but I don't understand why.

Comment: This seems like it relates more to how you're sending the query rather than your client configuration.

Comment: I'm using the ApolloProvider class which is part of the nextjs example code.   (updated question)